# Finding $\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need a short method to find $\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}$

Given $2y=x(1+\frac{dy}{dx})$, how do I find out $\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}$?

I tried to solve the differential equation by using this: Let $v=\frac{y}{x}$.
Rewriting, $2v=1+\frac{dy}{dx}=1+v+x\frac{dv}{dx}$  i.e. $\int \frac{dx}{x}=\int\frac{dv}{v-1}+ C$ i.e. $\log|x|=\log|v-1|+C$. After substituting $v=\frac{y}{x}$ back, I tried it but I seem to be getting nowhere. Any insight into this?

Comment: Do you know about *implicit differentiation*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-arrange the equation to get $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2y-x}{x}$.

Then invert to get $\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{x}{2y-2}$.

Then you can differentiate both sides with respect to $y$.

I think you just overcomplicated the problem...